# I want to dynamically write messages into a div in my template. How can I do that?

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-template

I receive messages from a server and I want to write them into a div. I am having an absurd amount of trouble figuring out how to append strings onto the content of a div. How do I do that in my controller?

Comment: Can you plz share your code.

Answer (score 1):

In controller, You can assign your message in $scope object.

For example:

```
 var msg = '';

 function (mymsgs) {
    msg += mymsgs;
    $scope.messages = msg;
 }
```

After that, In the view or html, you can access the messages by using cruly brackets

```
 <div>{{messages}}</div>
```

let me know if you are facing any problem or share your code. I will modify

Comment: Ankit - thank you, but the problem is also that I want to display messages that arrive from time to time, appending them onto the end of the messages. Angular is just picking up the first assignment to mymessages, and does not display the rest.

Comment: I edited,Please check,If possible can you please share your code so that i will modify